# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage'

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have a long list of images  which I want to add their img.src values by their number. I'm using the following code to scroll through the images. I have to use the img control as the images are .tif

```
foreach (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage c in ThumbnailPanel.Controls)
{
    if (c is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage imageBox = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage)c;

        if (imageBox.ID.Equals("TNimage" + i.ToString()))
        {
           using (var DrawImgCheck = new WebClient())
           {
             .
             .
             .
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is because  is an HtmlControl and my panel is a UI.Control I get the following error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage'.
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `foreach` loop, use this:

```
ThumbnailPanel.Controls.OfType<System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage>()
```

instead of:

```
ThumbnailPanel.Controls
```

That also means that in the loop, you don't need this line:

```
if (c is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage)
```

or this one:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage imageBox =
    (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage)c;
```

`c` will already be the right type.

---

Now consider the original problem. You could have also changed the `foreach` to be this:

```
foreach (var c in ThumbnailPanel.Controls)
```

and it would have compiled because `var` would have evaluated to `Control`. However, it's really not necessary to do all of that checking now because of the `OfType` method. It's a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried this and got the following error when compiling 'Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you intend to invoke the 'method group'?'

Comment: I've added the () on the end and it has worked fine, many thanks